# Maximum occurrence of string from a character variable in R

Tags: r, data-cleaning

I have a data frame which has two columns(hospital name, type).Both the variables are character variables. The data is as showcased below :-

```
hospital_name  type
ABC            rural
ABC            rural
ABC            urban
XYZ            urban
XYZ            urban
EFG            rural
```

I am working on a code that will group by hospital name and take a count of each type within that group. Next, create a new column called type2 which will have the value of highest occurrence in type column. The desired out put should be :-

```
hospital_name  type  type2
ABC            rural rural
XYZ            urban urban
EFG            rural rural
```

I approached this problem using dplyr but I am getting error. Here is my solution :-

```
library("dplyr")
df<-df%>%group_by(hospital_name)%>%mutate(type2=names(which.max(table(type))))
```

The error is  :-

```
Error: incompatible types, expecting a character vector
```

Comment: Detached plyr and my dplyr version is 0.4.2. But still get the same error.

Comment: You could use `count(df, hospital_name, type) %>% slice(which.max(n)) %>% ungroup %>% select(-n)`. And for your own attempt, try it like this: `df %>%group_by(hospital_name)%>%dplyr::mutate(type2=names(which.max(table(type))))`

Comment: May you add a `dput()` of your exemple dataframe ? Isn't there a factor somewhere ?

Comment: @brittenb Its character in both the cases.

Comment: @brittenb Updated to 0.4.3 but the error remains - Error: incompatible types, expecting a character vector

Comment: @brittenb The type column has other values as well like "sub-urban". Is there an issue because of this?

Comment: structure(list(NET_PARENT = c("COMMUNITY HEALTH SYSTEMS (CHS)", 
"JEFFERSON HEALTH", "JEFFERSON HEALTH", "MEMORIAL HEALTH SYSTEM (SPRINGFIELD IL)", 
"TENET HEALTHCARE", "TENET HEALTHCARE", "TENET HEALTHCARE", "TENET HEALTHCARE", 
"LIFEPOINT HEALTH (FKA: LIFEPOINT HOSPITALS)", "INDIAN HEALTH SERVICES"
), OWNERSHIP = c("for_profit", "non-profit", "non-profit", "non-profit", 
"for_profit", "for_profit", "for_profit", "for_profit", "for_profit", 
"public")), .Names = c("NET_PARENT", "OWNERSHIP"), row.names = c(1L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 10L, 13L), class = "data.frame")

Comment: @brittenb I had changed the column names and contents in the data frame. The dput() output is from the original data.

Comment: @brittenb The issue is - there are couple of NA`s in type column which is leading to this problem. Is there a way to handle it? If I delete the rows with NA and run the code, your code works fine.

Comment: @x1carbon Please see the updated answer. I was able to solve your problem. In the future, please make sure that your minimal, reproducible example actually encompasses the issue at hand.

Answer (score 5):

Given that your code above runs without error, but doesn't produce the desired output, I'd tweak it only slightly to get what you want:

```
dat <- dplyr::data_frame(hospital_name = c("ABC", "ABC", "ABC", "XYZ", "XYZ", "EFG"), 
                         type = c("rural", "rural", "urban", "urban", "urban", "rural"))

dat %>% group_by(hospital_name) %>% 
  mutate(type2 = names(which.max(table(type)))) %>% 
  filter(type == type2) %>% 
  distinct()

dat
# Source: local data frame [3 x 3]
# Groups: hospital_name [3]
#
#   hospital_name  type type2
#           (chr) (chr) (chr)
# 1           ABC rural rural
# 2           XYZ urban urban
# 3           EFG rural rural
```

### Update

The comments above indicate that the data has `NA` in the `type` column, which is what seems to be throwing the error. However, this doesn't seem to be an issue on my machine.

```
dat <- data.frame(hospital_name = c("ABC", "ABC", "ABC", "XYZ", "XYZ", "EFG"), 
                  type = c("rural", "rural", "urban", "urban", NA, "rural"))
dat
#   hospital_name  type
# 1           ABC rural
# 2           ABC rural
# 3           ABC urban
# 4           XYZ urban
# 5           XYZ  <NA>
# 6           EFG rural

sapply(dat, class)
# hospital_name          type 
#      "factor"      "factor" 

dat %>% 
  group_by(hospital_name) %>% 
  mutate(type2 = names(which.max(table(type))))

# Source: local data frame [6 x 3]
# Groups: hospital_name [3]

#   hospital_name   type type2
#          (fctr) (fctr) (chr)
# 1           ABC  rural rural
# 2           ABC  rural rural
# 3           ABC  urban rural
# 4           XYZ  urban urban
# 5           XYZ     NA urban
# 6           EFG  rural rural
```

### Update 2

So I have finally been able to reproduce your error.

```
dat <- structure(list(NET_PARENT = c("COMMUNITY HEALTH SYSTEMS (CHS)", 
"JEFFERSON HEALTH", "JEFFERSON HEALTH", "MEMORIAL HEALTH SYSTEM (SPRINGFIELD IL)", 
"TENET HEALTHCARE", "TENET HEALTHCARE", "TENET HEALTHCARE", "TENET HEALTHCARE", 
"LIFEPOINT HEALTH (FKA: LIFEPOINT HOSPITALS)", "INDIAN HEALTH SERVICES"
), OWNERSHIP = c("for_profit", "non-profit", "non-profit", "non-profit", 
"for_profit", NA, NA, NA, "for_profit", NA)), .Names = c("NET_PARENT", 
"OWNERSHIP"), row.names = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 10L, 
13L), class = "data.frame")

dat

#                                     NET_PARENT  OWNERSHIP
# 1               COMMUNITY HEALTH SYSTEMS (CHS) for_profit
# 2                             JEFFERSON HEALTH non-profit
# 3                             JEFFERSON HEALTH non-profit
# 4      MEMORIAL HEALTH SYSTEM (SPRINGFIELD IL) non-profit
# 5                             TENET HEALTHCARE for_profit
# 6                             TENET HEALTHCARE       <NA>
# 7                             TENET HEALTHCARE       <NA>
# 8                             TENET HEALTHCARE       <NA>
# 10 LIFEPOINT HEALTH (FKA: LIFEPOINT HOSPITALS) for_profit
# 13                      INDIAN HEALTH SERVICES       <NA>

dat %>% group_by(NET_PARENT) %>% mutate(type2 = names(which.max(table(OWNERSHIP)))
# Error: incompatible types, expecting a character vector
```

This is happening because the most popular option for both `dat$NET_PARENT == "INDIAN HEALTH SERVICES"` and `dat$NET_PARENT == "TENET HEALTHCARE"` is `NA`. This throws an error in `mutate` because it wants a `character` value and instead gets a `NULL` value. We can fix this with the following change.

```
dat %>%
  group_by(NET_PARENT) %>%
  mutate(type2 = ifelse(length(which.max(table(OWNERSHIP))) == 0,
                        "NA",
                        names(which.max(table(OWNERSHIP)))))

# Source: local data frame [10 x 3]
# Groups: NET_PARENT [6]

#                                     NET_PARENT  OWNERSHIP      type2
#                                          (chr)      (chr)      (chr)
# 1               COMMUNITY HEALTH SYSTEMS (CHS) for_profit for_profit
# 2                             JEFFERSON HEALTH non-profit non-profit
# 3                             JEFFERSON HEALTH non-profit non-profit
# 4      MEMORIAL HEALTH SYSTEM (SPRINGFIELD IL) non-profit non-profit
# 5                             TENET HEALTHCARE for_profit for_profit
# 6                             TENET HEALTHCARE         NA for_profit
# 7                             TENET HEALTHCARE         NA for_profit
# 8                             TENET HEALTHCARE         NA for_profit
# 9  LIFEPOINT HEALTH (FKA: LIFEPOINT HOSPITALS) for_profit for_profit
# 10                      INDIAN HEALTH SERVICES         NA         NA
```

Notice that `type2` is "for_profit" for "TENET HEALTHCARE" even though the max value is `NA`. This is because `table` doesn't capture the `NA` and it is omitted from the values. As a result, the only value there is what is recorded as the max. But for "INDIAN HEALTH SERVICES", it is listed as "NA".

Comment: This one is a better solution. Plus one.

Comment: I still get this error - Error: incompatible types, expecting a character vector

Comment: Thanks. When I check the class using sapply. Its character in both the cases. Is this an issues? NET_PARENT   OWNERSHIP 
"character" "character"